# C - Deleting Node when there's only 1 element in a single Linked List

Tags: c, nodes, singly-linked-list

Hey guys, So I understand that to delete nodes when there are multiple elements in a linked list, you take the previous node from the current node which you want to be deleted and point it to `current->next`, and then you `free()` the current Node.

But my issue is when I only have one element in a single Linked List, I seem to get segmentation fault(core dump) when I try to delete the node, I'm assuming it is because in this scenario `current->next` would point to `NULL` (I might be wrong here). Also Let's say I have a node that stores a value of 5, a common problem I run into is instead of deleting the node, it changes the value to 0.

Question:
I am not asking anyone to fix my code, which is why I decided not to post code, but my question is how would I approach this deleting a node when it is the only element in the linked list? How does deleting a node that only has one element in the linked list different to when there are multiple elements.

Thank you so much for your help, I am sorry if things are unclear, but I really wanted to give context first before asking my question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [_How To Ask A Good Question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [_How To Create A Minimal, Complete, And Verifiable Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should probably have a pointer named `head`. `free` memory of single element than set `head` to `NULL`.

Comment: When dealing with linked lists, I really recommend you do it all on paper first, using boxes for the nodes and arrows for the links. Draw up all your cases (there are really only four cases: node first in list, node last in list, node only in list, and node in middle of list), and attempt to "remove" the node by redrawing the arrows. When you think you got it, *then* write code to do it. And always test your newly written code *before* you continue with the next bit. Do this for all operations on your list, starting with adding nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In linked list, deletion of node can be done in different way.

#### A) Deletion of first node

Algorithm:

```
Step1: temp = head
Step2: temp = temp->next
Step3: free(temp)
Step4: head = NULL
```

#### B) Deletion of Last node

Algorithm

```
Step1: p = head
Step2: while p->next->next != NULL 
         p = p->next
Step3: temp = p->next
Step4: p->next = NULL
Step5: free(temp)
```

#### C) Deletion of node in between.

Algorithm:

```
Step1: p = head
Step2: while POSITION > 2 #Indexing from 1
         p = p->next
         POSITION = POSITION - 1
Step3: temp = p->next
Step4: p->next = p->next->next
Step5: free(temp)
```

Comment: Thank you for the review

Answer (score 0):

Your "linked list" is just a pointer on the first element of your list.

```
MyStruct *my_list;
```

So, if my_list->next is null, it's means it's you have only one element in your list.
If you want remove him, it's simple :

```
free(my_list)
my_list = NULL;
```

Your list is now empty (don't try to read this ;) )

Answer (score 0):

When removing an element from a list, there are two special cases to worry about: the first element and the last element, and sometimes they are the same element.

Both can be handled like this:

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void deleteNode(node **head, int value) {
    node *prev = NULL, *curr = *head;

    // look for the node to delete
    while (curr && curr->value != value) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (curr == NULL) {
        printf("node to delete not found\n");
    } else if (prev == NULL) {
        // need to delete the first node, so repoint head to next node
        *head = (*head)->next;
    } else {
        // deleting an internal node, so have the previous point to the current's next
        prev->next = curr->next;
    }
    // no need to check for the last node 
    // since we're copying next which may or may not be NULL

    free(curr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your implementation of linked list.

A few possible implementations are possible.

- linear linked list with external pointer to start node

  - pointer to NULL if empty
  - last node NULL
- circular linked lists with external pointer to the start node

  - if only one element, it points to itself and the external element points to the only element
  - if no element the external pointer is NULL
- circular linked lists with one element as the head element

  - if empty the head-element points to itself
- encapsulated into structure

  - one of the above link schemes
  - with additional end pointer for faster end-insertion

Depending on the structure of the list the implementation may differ.

On general base you can say, that you start with a pointer `H`, that points to an element `E` and that element has a `next` pointer to the successor `S`.

You are right that you set `H` to content of `next`. since `H` and `E` has to be valid, there should no segmentation fault.

On the most simple form (unchecked/uncompiled code - should just show the principle):

```
typedef struct ListNode{
  void* data,
  struct ListNode* next;
}ListNode;

/**
  *  \brief  removes an element from the linked list 
  *
  *  \param  io_el  the 'next' pointer of the previous 
  *                 element or the pointer to the head
  *  \return the pointer to the removed element
  *  
  *  \details
  *  uses the io_el pointer to advance to the next list element and 
  *  sets the io_el pointer to the content of the next pointer of
  *  this element. This effectivly removes the element from the chain.
  *  The removed element is returned so that it may be free'd if necessary. 
  */
Node* ListDeleteElement(Node** io_el){
  Node* res = NULL;
  if( io_el && *io_el){
    res = *io_el;
    *io_el = (*io_el)->next;
  }
}
```

considering the following list.

```
Node E1 ,E2,E3;
Node* H = &E1;
E1.next = &E2;
E2.next = &E3;
E3.next = NULL;

// (H = ) E1 -> E2 -> E3 -> NULL

// remove E3;
ListDeleteElement( &(H->next->next) ); // passes pointer to the nextpointer of E2, 
// E2.next should be NULL now
// (H = ) E1 -> E2 -> NULL

// remove E1
ListDeleteElement( &H ); 
// *H should now be E2
// (H = ) E2 -> NULL

// again remove first element
ListDeleteElement( &H ); 
// (H = ) NULL
```

This implementation is kind of dangerous - it is absolutely necessary that the passed pointer is the pointer to head or a pointer to a `next` pointer of an actual element of the list.

Passing addresses of arbitrary pointer into the list structure damages the list.

So this code should be used as internal helper function that is been wrapped by some more high level function or should be used in small local lists in that are not passed to other program parts. In this case i would design a more robust list class.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a node which is **not** the first node the steps are

1) `previous_node->next = node_to_delete->next;`

2) `free(node_to_delete)`

When you delete a node which **is** the first node you **skip step 1** as there is no previous_node. Instead you have to update the head of the list like:

3) `head = node_to_delete->next;`

This can be implemented in many ways. For instance something like:

```
node* delete(node* head, int n)
{
    node* prev = NULL;
    node* temp = head;

    while (temp)
    {
        if (temp->value == n) 
        {
            if (prev)
            {
                // All except first node
                prev->next = temp->next;
            }
            else
            {
                // First node
                head = temp->next;
            }
            free(temp);
            return head;
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

and call it like:

```
head = delete(head, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

1: If the element is the head.

```
   nodeptr deleteBeginning(nodeptr head){
        nodeptr current = head;
        head= head->next;
        free(current);
        return head;
   }
```

2: For the rest of the elements.

```
   nodeptr deleteNode(nodeptr head, int value){
    if(value == head->data) {
        head = deleteBeginning(head);
        return head;
    }

    nodeptr current = head;
    nodeptr previous;

    while(current->data != value){
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    previous->next = current->next;
    free(current);
    return head;
   }
```

nodeptr is just the typedef for struct Node*